# Revisão de perguntas ou respostas em pt_PT para pt_BR ou vice-versa, como agir?

Tags: debate, edição, proposta-para-faq, diferenças-regionais

Surgiu este caso numa resposta minha, eu sou Português de Portugal e uma resposta das respostas que coloquei foi editada e revista pela comunidade:

[Atributo “href” para links em JavaScript: “#” ou “javascript:void(0)”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/773/atributo-href-para-links-em-javascript-ou-javascriptvoid0/780#780)

Onde na fila de revisões quando pude ver a notificação sobre a sugestão de edição estava:

[image: Analise]

Eu sou da opinião do que o [bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/462) disse:

> O autor é português, o site é em português. Não acho que todo o conteúdo deva ser adaptado para português brasileiro.

E nesse mesmo entendimento, reverti a edição para a versão anterior.

Contudo, o hernandes e o BrunoLM concordaram com a edição sugerida, e os seus votos fizeram com que a mesma fosse efetivada.

Obviamente, temos pontos de vista diferentes em relação a isto e é preciso definir uma regra ou vamos andar sempre para trás e para a frente com edições e revisões.

## Pergunta:

O que fazer quando vemos uma pergunta ou resposta a ser editada unicamente para passar o conteúdo de pt_PT para pt_BR e vice-versa?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Acho que não deve ser aceite

Sempre foi do meu entendimento que as edições devem ser substanciais e proveitosas, ou seja, uma edição deve cobrir vários aspetos do conteúdo a ser editado, e deve ter algum significado do tipo: erros gramaticais, frases mal construídas, ausência ou fraca formatação, passagem de conteúdos nos comentários para a pergunta de forma a limpar ou reduzir comentários, entre outros.

Editar para realizar pequenos ajustes, o que penso ser o caso de trocar palavras pt_PT para pt_BR ou vice-versa é irrelevante ao melhoramento do conteúdo e só vai trazer trabalho extra para os revisores.

Comment: Concordo totalmente. Inclusive isso já foi discutido em linhas gerais aqui: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/3/deveremos-de-manter-algum-standard-linguistico-ou-nao e a opinião é que podemos nos entender perfeitamente cada um escrevendo dentro da sua cultura. Não há vantagem alguma em padronizar a escrita. Há sim, desvantagens.

Comment: Concordo que não deve ser aceito. Ontem estava testando as revisões e acabei não prestando muita atenção, não vi em detalhes, pareciam correções legitimas, só depois que aprovei que percebi que era pt de portugal. Peço desculpas.

Comment: @BrunoLM Não é preciso pedir desculpa, até foi bom porque assim deu origem a esta discussão e podemos todos chegar a um consenso :)

Comment: desculpe minha ignorância quanto aos padrões pt_pt ,mas a expressão "Acho que não deva ser aceite", segundo meu padrão de pt_br está errada e deveria ser "Acho que não deveria ser aceita", com "a" no final. Em pt_pt está correto?

Comment: A idéia não é criar uma nova discussão, é esclarecer as diferenças de forma a ampliar o escopo de possibilidades dessas diferenças. Concordo que edições para regionalizações não devam ser aceitas.

Comment: @LuizAngioletti Em "pt_PT" uma pessoa _aceita_ algo, mas diz que a proposta foi _aceite_ ou _recusada_ :) (Não sei se clarifica, mas básicamente em "pt_PT" está correcto como escrevi). Todavia podes ver [neste link](http://www.ciberduvidas.com/pergunta.php?id=405) que ambas as maneiras estão correctas!

Comment: @Zuul, adorei o link, e estou adorando a oportunidade de aprender mais português por aqui. =)

Comment: @Zuul já agora, "basicamente" (em pt-PT) não é acentuado de forma gráfica.

Answer (score 13):

> <sub>Esta resposta era da época do endereço **br**.stackoverflow.com. O site finalmente graduou como **pt**.stackoverflow.com. A resposta permanece apenas por questão "histórica". Se alguém achar melhor a remoção, deixe um comentário.</sub>

Eu acho que começa do problema do nome do site. No logotipo está Stack Overflow em 
português, mas o endereço é http://BR.stackoverflow.com

Sou a favor de adotar pt.stackoverflow.com e nao discutir o português (salvo quando estiver errado, e não regionalizado), mas se for permanecer o br. em vez de pt. é sensato que se mantenha o português Br, e que se atualize o logotipo para StackOverflow Brasil.

O que não dá é pra ficar na indefinição.

Comment: Também acho que o endereço deveria ser pt.stackoverflow.com. Ver: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/50/o-dominio-do-site-sera-br-stackoverflow-com-mesmo

Comment: Bem, eu concordo com a resposta do Gabe.

Comment: @BrunoLM O Gabe diz um monte de coisa que faz sentido ali, mas que não justificam o "br" no domínio. Estou falando exclusivamente disso, não acho que o site deva ter Brasil no nome. Nem no domínio.