# Onde está o conjunto de regras?

Tags: suporte, comportamento

Quando eu vou fazer edições de perguntas, eu, volta e meia, tenho dúvidas se o que estou fazendo é correto ou incorreto. Prova disso foi uma questão que eu editei, a qual estava em pt-PT e modifiquei para pt-BR, pois estava acostumado com o `br.stackoverflow.com`, apesar dele ter mudado hoje para `pt.stackoverflow.com`.
Quando me deparei com essa dúvida em específico, recorri ao meta e encontrei [essa resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292/revisao-de-perguntas-ou-respostas-em-pt-pt-para-pt-br-ou-vice-versa-como-agir), que mostrou que o que eu estava fazendo era errado, segundo o que [foi proposto pela comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293/1333).

Então, eu queria saber se existe e (caso exista) onde estão o conjunto de regras para edição, rebaixar uma questão, entre outros aspectos. Existe alguma página assim?

Comment: Uma das coisas que deve te interessar é sobre a rejeição de algumas edições. Em geral, edições que pouco acrescentam ao post editado, são rejeitados. Você vai dizer "mas vocês fazem muito essas edições". Existe uma diferença, nós não ganhamos reputação por essas edições. É mal visto ganhar +2 de reputação porque trocou a formatação de link ou por ter trocado aspas por asterisco. E quando você se torna experiente, vê quando vale à pena melhor e quando é melhor deixar do jeito que está.

Comment: Bom saber, porque eu estava fazendo isso direto e não sabia que era uma prática ruim. A partir de quanto de rep as edições param de dar +2?

Comment: Agora que saiu do beta privado eu não sei mais, era 500, não sei se mudou. Edite o que realmente é importante, isso ajuda mas deixe **pequenas** formatações para depois.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As regras ainda estão sendo construídas/definidas, então está tudo meio espalhado por enquanto. De oficial da rede Stack Exchange tem os primeiros posts aqui do meta, com a tag [destaque](/questions/tagged/destaque):

- [Aqui NÃO É o stackoverflow.com](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-no-o-stackoverflow-com)
- [Como construir o site que você quer ser quando crescer](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2/como-construir-o-site-que-voce-quer-ser-quando-crescer)

Tem também o post do blog, postado assim que o site entrou no beta público:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/ola-mundo-announcing-stack-overflow-in-portuguese/?cb=1

E tem a [central de ajuda do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help), com bastante conteúdo que acabou de ser traduzido do inglês.

Fora isso, há várias postagens aqui no meta com as tags [debate](/questions/tagged/debate) e [big-7](/questions/tagged/big-7), discutindo tudo o que vai aparecendo. Entre elas eu destacaria:

- [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective) (traduzida do blog)
- [Quais assuntos devem fazer parte do nosso foco (on-topic)?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic)
- [Vote cedo, vote frequentemente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente)

Vou parar por aqui porque a lista é bem grande – e mesmo assim ainda não cobre tudo. Estamos contruindo as regras juntos, então fique de olho no meta e participe das discussões!